# Windows Phone 8.1 with DirectXTK

Tags: directx, windows-phone-8.1

When I try to add a reference (DirectXTK) to my native part of the WP8.1 project I got the following message: A reference to 'DirectXTK' cannot be added because the two projects target different platforms.

Anyone experienced this behavior before?

My project is based on DirectX and XAML App (Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1) app template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered on the [CodePlex](https://directxtk.codeplex.com/workitem/1204).

In short, you have to create a "Static Library (Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1)" project for DirectXTK.